# Release UIViewController ARC (using the linking method (no programming)to relate views)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, release

I`ve searched a lot about this problem but I didn´t find anything, hoping someone does it, here is my question:

I`ve tested the app in the simulator a lot of times. I have ARC and all the outlets released in the viewDidUnload (I`ve quite a lot of images). When I run it on the simulator, the memory continues rising again and again, when changing between views.

For example, I have a button in a view. And right clicking it, I drag it to another view, connecting them. Do I need to release anything relating in this way the views? If so, where I put the code? (I have a .h and .m for each view).I have read a lot of questions like this, but all off them referred to views related by code, not using the drag option 
(Style - modal)

Please I would thank a lot any clue or help, as I have to solve this problem in a short period of time,

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is not called anymore starting with iOS6. That might explain what is happening.

> Called when the controller’s view is released from memory. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.)

Furthermore, `viewDidUnload` was usually called when the view was unloaded due to memory pressure, so you were anyway expected to call it from your `dealloc` method.

Try doing your niling in `dealloc` or `viewDidDisappear`.

You should also be aware, if you use [`UIImage`'s `imageNamed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a) to load your images, that this method will cache the images. So even when you remove them from your views they remain in the system's cache.

Without seeing your code it is not possible to say more than this.

Comment: without code it is not very easy to answer. you can define `dealloc` in you class (without calling `[super dealloc]`); but I guess that in your case it is better to do the nil-ing in viewDidDisappear (otherwise I don't know why you were doing it in `viewDidUnload` in the first place). about the cache, the only thing you can do is using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead of `imageNamed`. but there is a chance that on a device the cache is emptied when memory is low. years ago there was a bug and this was not true, I do not know as of now.

Comment: I have had a look at your files, but it is not apparent where the problem is. On the other hand, you say memory grows "when changing between views" -- how do you change between views? how do you use your desayuno class? would you also mind testing on a device, because if memory never gets short, iOS will not try to recover it...

Comment: I dont use any code to change between views, i just in the .storyboard  right click on a button and drag it to the other view (Action segue_modal). I have tested on different targets and as the have less memory ram, the situation is worst